# Android WiFi Hotspot creating One to Many connectivity

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifip2p

- I am developing game in which I want to connect multiple people through wifi hotspot in game.
- I followed this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_wi_fi.htm) but it does not fulfill the requirements needed for this scenario because I want to get device list using wifi only In which my game is installed and do the same thing exactly as Xender.
- I have tried WiFi direct but that is very poor service sometimes devices are taking too long time to transfer data and even the connection gets disconnected automatically.
- so It seems not good with wifi direct.

How do I create one to many connectivity in this scenario using **WIFI HOTSPOT**?

Comment: Which problems do you have? Dont assume we follow that link or know anything from Xender.

Comment: That you already told. We knew that already. You dont want wifi-direct.  So now you want to use wifi over hotspot you said. So what kind of problems do you have with it was the question.

Comment: In wifi hotspot, the api is giving all wifi connection list so it is difficult to identify which one is created using hotspot. another thing is I am unable to find any callback methods like wifi direct have. (just as peers available callback everytime, connection info available, connected, disconneted etc callbacks.)

Comment: There will be a device for every gamer. There will be only one hotspot. Its unclear about which device you were talking summing up the problems. Please come to the point.

Comment: yes every gamer will have a device and suppose four people wants to play the game one of those (server) creates group and remaining all(clients) will join it. but when I am getting wifi connection list, It gives me all connection list of routers' wifi and other in which I have created hotspot. so how can I identify that hotspot device which is created using my game. And also I tried to connect the devices but that doesn't happening...so I need to know that how do I actually achieve this connectivity and transfer data.

Comment: `but when I am getting wifi connection list, .....` On which device? I specifically asked you to mention the device you were talking about.

Comment: `one of those (server) creates group`. What is a group? It smells like wifi-direct.

Comment: One of the devices creates a hotspot. The other devices have to connect to that hotspot. So the users on those devices see all wifi stations in the neighbourhood. So the user has to choose the right one. The user has to know the name/ssid. But you want more? Like the user does not know the name/ssid but sees ... yes sees something that distinghuises your spot from the others?

Comment: `And also I tried to connect the devices`. It is unclear what you tried.